# Issue of TextCompletion of AutoCompleteBox in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I have created my own cutom control in combination of two :
button and a autocompletebox in silverlight.

On a click event of a button i bind the itemsource of a autocompletebox and do this :

```
acb.ItemsSource = p.ToArray();//list of an object of a class(person)
        acb.MinimumPrefixLength = 0;
        acb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```

And on a textchanged event of a autocompletebox i call a service method to fetch persons based on the search text and do this :

```
 ReferringProvider.ItemsSource = searchproviders;              
 this.ReferringProvider.tbComboValue.MinimumPrefixLength = 0;
 this.ReferringProvider.tbComboValue.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```

---

```
But i lose TextCompletion, the text is not completed with the first item of drop downlist?
```

Any idea  why so? or any suggestions

Please Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog sometime back on autocomplete text box, but I did not use button. I am not sure you need button to initiate autocomplete. Corrent me I am wrong.

http://csharprambling.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/autocompletebox-to-auto-complete-data-entry/